# Executed create index concurrently statmt & it was disconnected session due to timeout error.but I do see in pg_stat_activity,it is in running state

Tags: postgresql, indexing, postgresql-9.6, pgadmin-4

I have executed create an index on a big table from pgAdmin, and in a while, I lost connection to the server, so the execution window closed in pgAdnin. Then I reconnected to the server, and when checked  pg_stat_activity, I do see that the create index statement is running (active) state, I just wondering to know whether this index being creating or stuck somewhere?

1. client disconnected with error,
   cancelling statement due to statement timeout
2. when I reconnected to the server, in pg_stat_activity.
   31937    "edsadmin"  "09:54:44.280176"   "CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY idx_src_record_date
   ON pcd_t.l_esd_detail_report USING btree
   (src_record_date COLLATE pg_catalog."default")
   TABLESPACE pg_default;"

I'm really confused here wheather it is createing or not.

Comment: Please correct me some if were I'm wrong, As of workaround experience when we executed create index with concurrently, it will create index backend even your connection lost due to time out error.

Comment: Great question. I'm also wondering about this. Nothing in the docs says what happens to the query if the client who calls the query drops connection to the DB.

Comment: Great question. I'm also wondering about this. Nothing in the docs says what happens to the query if the client who calls the query drops connection to the DB.

Comment: I noticed that index is being created even if connection closed at client end.

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, but relevant none-the-less.

Based on my anecdotal experience right now, the index creation persists beyond the lifetime of the client.

I did the following:

```
database=> CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY IX_myIndex on table(column, column2);
```

It paused for a few minutes, then:

```
SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected
The connection to the server was lost. Attempting reset: Succeeded.
psql (14.2 (Debian 14.2-1.pgdg110+1), server 10.18)
```

Immediately after reconnecting, I ran:

```
database=> \d table
                       Table "public.table"
     Column      |            Type             | Collation | Nullable | 
Default
-----------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
... blah blah blah ...
Indexes:
    "IX_myIndex" btree (column, column2) INVALID
```

I waited a few more minutes, then checked again:

```
database=> \d table
                       Table "public.table"
     Column      |            Type             | Collation | Nullable | 
Default
-----------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
... blah blah blah ...
Indexes:
    "IX_myIndex" btree (column, column2)
```

So, your index is likely fine.